# np.array(filter(func,iter)) not producing an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

`np.array` does accept an iterable. So passing it the result of `filter` should produce an array. However as the example below illustrates, it doesn't. Infact one needs to wrap the result in `list`. Why is this so?

```py
import numpy as np
rects=np.random.randint(0,100,[10,4])
def crit_(rect):
    x,y,w,h=rect
    return x>10 and y>10 and w>10 and h>10

print(np.array(filter(crit_,rects)))
# <filter object at 0x000001F5888EE8C8>
print(np.array(list(filter(crit_,rects)))[:3])
#[[55 98 57 38]
 # [48 59 81 18]
 # [87 27 20 72]]
```

Comment: why do you think that numpy.array accepts iterables? It doesn't in general.

Comment: @emilaz  what are you talking about? try: `np.array(range(5))`

Comment: The `np.array` docs mention a `(nested) sequence`, not `an iterable`.

Comment: @Nullman try: `np.array(iter(range(5))))` . It doesn't work in the general case.

Comment: @emilaz I was using pycharm where it showed that `np.array` has signature `p_object:Union[ndarray,Iterable,int,float],...`

Comment: Then `pycharm` isn't accurate.  In general, `generators` are not widely used with `numpy`.  We try to avoid Python level iteration, preferring to do that in compiled numpy methods.

Answer (score 2):

Use [numpy.fromiter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) to create a new 1-dimensional array from an iterable object.

```
iterable = (x*x for x in range(5))
np.fromiter(iterable, float)
```

Comment: `print(np.fromiter(filter(crit_,rects),int))` gives ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: Your filter yields arrays but you promised fromiter to give it an iterator that yields int

Comment: you cant do it with [fromiter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html#numpy.fromiter) the documentation states "Create a new **1-dimensional array** from an iterable object."

Comment: You could flatten the filter object and reshape the array later.

Comment: but filter produces an iterator as stated here https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter so `fromiter` shouldn't have a problem. Also, you have wrapped the generator in a tuple same as using `list(filter...`in my example.

Comment: @lineage yes but your iterator returns arrays and fromiter expects single values, it can only make 1d array and you are making 2d arrays

Answer (score 1):

You can do with [vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)

```
np.vstack(filter(crit_,rects))
```

Answer (score 1):

As illustrated below, np.array doesn't accept iterators

```py
f=filter(crit_,rects)
print(issubclass(f.__class__,collections.Iterator))
#True
print(np.array(f))
# <filter object at 0x000001F5888EE8C8>


r=range(5)
print(issubclass(r.__class__,collections.Iterator))
#False
print(np.array(r))
#[0 1 2 3 4]
ls=list(f)
print(issubclass(ls.__class__,collections.Iterator))
#False
print(np.array(ls))
#[[89 13 67 79]
# [48 11 46 99]
# [57 71 65 65]]
```

`np.array` doesn't accept iterators

Answer (score 0):

```
In [50]: rects=np.random.randint(0,100,[10,4]) 
    ...: def crit_(rect): 
    ...:     x,y,w,h=rect 
    ...:     return x>10 and y>10 and w>10 and h>10 
    ...:                                                                                                                   
In [51]: filter(crit_,rects)                                                                                               
Out[51]: <filter at 0x7f55a1a43ac8>
In [52]: list(_)                                                                                                           
Out[52]: 
[array([43, 57, 85, 93]),
 array([30, 22, 19, 55]),
 array([12, 96, 48, 40]),
 array([48, 13, 37, 46]),
 array([49, 15, 35, 32]),
 array([81, 81, 96, 57])]
```

`vstack` works, but gives a warning:

```
In [53]: np.vstack(filter(crit_,rects))                                                                                    
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: FutureWarning: arrays to stack must be passed as a "sequence" type such as list or tuple. Support for non-sequence iterables such as generators is deprecated as of NumPy 1.16 and will raise an error in the future.
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[53]: 
array([[43, 57, 85, 93],
       [30, 22, 19, 55],
       [12, 96, 48, 40],
       [48, 13, 37, 46],
       [49, 15, 35, 32],
       [81, 81, 96, 57]])

In [55]: np.vstack(list(filter(crit_,rects)))                                                                              
Out[55]: 
array([[43, 57, 85, 93],
       [30, 22, 19, 55],
       [12, 96, 48, 40],
       [48, 13, 37, 46],
       [49, 15, 35, 32],
       [81, 81, 96, 57]])
```

without the filter/iteration:

```
In [60]: rects[(rects>10).all(axis=1)]                                                                                     
Out[60]: 
array([[43, 57, 85, 93],
       [30, 22, 19, 55],
       [12, 96, 48, 40],
       [48, 13, 37, 46],
       [49, 15, 35, 32],
       [81, 81, 96, 57]])
```